# Forward filling based on the value of other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

**Update:**
I have a large pandas dataframe with admitTime, dischargeTime, pat_name, pat_rec and it has around 5 million records.  I am trying to forward fill the columns dischargeTime, pat_name, based on the dischargeTime datetime value for rest of the columns and break after that.

df:

`admitTime               dischargeTime      pat_name     pat_rec

2013-12-23 20:20:30    2013-12-23 21:03:00     Alex         A4536

2013-12-23 21:00:30
2013-12-23 21:01:00
2013-12-23 21:01:30
2013-12-23 21:02:00
2013-12-23 21:02:30
2013-12-23 21:03:00
2013-12-23 21:03:30
2013-12-23 21:04:00
2013-12-23 21:04:30
2013-12-23 21:05:00    2013-12-23 21:08:30    Sam          A4523
2013-12-23 21:06:00
2013-12-23 21:06:30
2013-12-23 21:07:00
2013-12-23 21:07:30
2013-12-23 21:08:00
2013-12-23 21:08:30
2013-12-23 21:09:00
2013-12-23 21:09:30    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike        A9873
2013-12-23 21:10:00
2013-12-23 21:10:30
2013-12-23 21:11:00
2013-12-23 21:11:30
2013-12-23 21:12:00
2013-12-23 21:12:30
2013-12-23 21:13:00
2013-12-23 21:13:30
2013-12-23 21:14:00

2013-12-23 21:14:30`

Ideally I'd like my df to look like

`datetime                discchargeTime     pat_name   pat_rec

2013-12-23 20:20:30    2013-12-23 21:03:00   Alex      A4536

2013-12-23 21:00:30    2013-12-23 21:03:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:01:00    2013-12-23 21:03:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:01:30    2013-12-23 21:03:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:02:00    2013-12-23 21:03:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:02:30    2013-12-23 21:03:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:03:00    2013-12-23 21:03:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:03:30

2013-12-23 21:04:00

2013-12-23 21:04:30

2013-12-23 21:05:00    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:05:30    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:06:00    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:06:30    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:07:00    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:07:30    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:08:00    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:08:30    2013-12-23 21:08:30   Sam      A4523
2013-12-23 21:09:00

2013-12-23 21:09:30    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:10:00    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:10:30    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:11:00    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:11:30    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:12:00    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:12:30    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:13:00    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:13:30    2013-12-23 21:13:30    Mike     A9873
2013-12-23 21:14:00

2013-12-23 21:14:30`

I tried `df[column_name].ffill()` but later realized its not the right thing to do.

I would really appreciate if I can get any suggestions.

Comment: Too much data. Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: Hi coldspeed. Let me know if this is fine. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forward fill, *then* use a Boolean filter to revert values to `NaN`:

```
fill_cols = ['dischargeTime', 'pat_name', 'pat_rec']
df[fill_cols] = df[fill_cols].ffill()
df[fill_cols] = df[fill_cols].mask(df['admitTime'] > df['dischargeTime'])
```

Comment: The forward filling is not stopping when the admitime matches with datetime. It is still continuing to forward fill untill it finds the next record in dischargetime column

Comment: @ALB2345, Apologies, see update, you have to do this in 2 steps.